# (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream:[nginx]

Tags: django, python-2.7, nginx, gunicorn

I am working with configuring Django project with Nginx and Gunicorn.

While I am accessing my port `gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:8001` in Nginx server, I am getting the following error in my error log file;

> 2014/05/30 11:59:42 [crit] 4075#0: *6 connect() to 127.0.0.1:8001 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: `"http://127.0.0.1:8001/"`, host: "localhost:8080"

Below is the content of my `nginx.conf` file;

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

In the HTML page I am getting `502 Bad Gateway`.

What mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 993, accepted):

#### Disclaimer

Make sure there are no security implications for your use-case before running this.

#### Answer

I had a similar issue getting Fedora 20, Nginx, Node.js, and Ghost (blog) to work. It turns out my issue was due to **SELinux**.

This should solve the problem:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

#### Details

I checked for errors in the SELinux logs:

```
sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied
```

And found that running the following commands fixed my issue:

```
sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied | audit2allow -M mynginx
sudo semodule -i mynginx.pp
```

#### Option #2 (probably more secure)

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_relay 1
```

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152358/difference-between-selinux-booleans-httpd-can-network-relay-and-httpd-can-net

#### References

http://blog.frag-gustav.de/2013/07/21/nginx-selinux-me-mad/
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Where_to_find_SELinux_permission_denial_details
http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Managing_network_port_labels

Comment: thanks. I needed to `yum install policycoreutils-python` in order to get `audit2allow` first. Reference: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5012

Comment: See also [here](http://axilleas.me/en/blog/2013/selinux-policy-for-nginx-and-gitlab-unix-socket-in-fedora-19/).  In my case I had to add nginx to the group of the user in whose home directory the wwwroot was stored.

Comment: Sid's answer should be the accepted answer, it's better to use built-in policies rather than create your own, much less overhead, especially when dealing with multiple servers.

Comment: On Fedora 23 installing the `policycoreutils-python` did not provide the command `audit2allow`. After some research I found you should install the devel package`yum install policycoreutils-devel`. Reference: http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/61710.html

Comment: Can someone please tell me how someone would reverse these policy changes?

Comment: amazing, and also very criptic (not your answer, but that this is required). I installed two centos instances and one required it the other didn't, confusing. Also are there any security implications to this to be aware of?

Comment: I was on RHEL 7.2 and the "setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1" saved me. Big thank you!

Comment: Just never could have imagined that when the default welcome page is displayed but proxying an upstream server doesn't work, it is still the fault of a third-party security policy. I just focused my debugging effort on the config file... Though should have been able to find the error log earlier indeed.

Comment: This SHOULD be in the cherrpy and nginx documentation for many unix OSes, because I wasted 8 hours trying to figure it out after following all the docs!

Comment: Please note that setting httpd_can_network_connect may pose as a serious security risk on your public facing server if turned on. See [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/httpd_selinux.8.html) and [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1020441/594486)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spent almost whole day troubleshooting, you saved me. Why dont Nginx forum add this in their documentation.

Comment: The _relay made my day, thank you so much :) And this doc explains good: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152358/difference-between-selinux-booleans-httpd-can-network-relay-and-httpd-can-net

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the log file that should be checked!

Answer (score 229):

I’ve run into this problem too. Another solution is to toggle the SELinux boolean value for httpd network connect to `on` (Nginx uses the httpd label).

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on
```

To make the change persist use the -P flag.

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on -P
```

You can see a list of all available SELinux booleans for httpd using

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I updated from CentOS 6.5 -> 6.7 and it must have defaulted the value to off during the update, because it was working fine before the update. Simple fix.

Comment: Please note that setting httpd_can_network_connect may pose as a serious security risk on your public facing server if turned on. See [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/httpd_selinux.8.html) and [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1020441/594486)

Answer (score 30):

I have solved my problem by running my Nginx as the user I'm currently logged in with, *mulagala*.

By default the user as *nginx* is defined at the very top section of the `nginx.conf` file as seen below;

```
user nginx; # Default Nginx user
```

Change *nginx* to the name of your current user - here, *mulagala*.

```
user mulagala; # Custom Nginx user (as username of the current logged in user)
```

However, this may not address the actual problem and may actually have casual side effect(s).

For an effective solution, please refer to [Joseph Barbere's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24830777/6381711).

Answer (score 17):

Had a similar problem on Centos 7. When I tried to apply the solution prescribed by Sorin, I started moving in cycles. First I had a permission {write} denied. Then when I solved that I had a permission { connectto } denied. Then back again to permission {write } denied.

Following @Sid answer above of checking the flags using `getsebool -a | grep httpd` and toggling them I found that in addition to the httpd_can_network_connect being off. http_anon_write was also off resulting in permission denied write and permission denied {connectto}

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1501830505.174:799183): avc:  
denied  { write } for  pid=12144 comm="nginx" name="myroject.sock" 
dev="dm-2" ino=134718735 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 
tcontext=system_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=sock_file
```

Obtained using 
    sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied 
as explained above.

So I solved them one at a time, toggling the flags on one at a time.

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on -P
```

Then running the commands specified by @sorin and @Joseph above

```
sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied | 
audit2allow -M mynginx
sudo semodule -i mynginx.pp
```

Basically you can check the permissions set on setsebool and correlate that with the error obtained from grepp'ing' audit.log nginx, denied

Answer (score 16):

if "502 Bad Gateway" error throws on centos api url for api gateway proxy pass on nginx , run following command to solve the issue

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Check the user in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
2. Change ownership to user.

```
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/nginx
```

Answer (score 8):

1. For first see what is denied:

```
sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied
```

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1618940614.934:38415): avc:  denied  { connectto } for
pid=18016 comm="nginx" path="/home/deployer/project/tmp/sockets/puma.sock" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1
```

2. In my case it helps on CentOS7:

```
sudo setenforce 0

setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on -P
setsebool httpd_can_network_relay on -P
```

After you can see what is enable:

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

```
httpd_anon_write --> off
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on
httpd_can_check_spam --> off
httpd_can_connect_ftp --> off
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> off
httpd_can_connect_mythtv --> off
httpd_can_connect_zabbix --> off
httpd_can_network_connect --> on
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> on
httpd_can_network_memcache --> off
httpd_can_network_relay --> on
httpd_can_sendmail --> off
httpd_dbus_avahi --> off
httpd_dbus_sssd --> off
httpd_dontaudit_search_dirs --> off
httpd_enable_cgi --> off
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
httpd_enable_homedirs --> off
httpd_execmem --> off
httpd_graceful_shutdown --> on
httpd_manage_ipa --> off
httpd_mod_auth_ntlm_winbind --> off
httpd_mod_auth_pam --> off
httpd_read_user_content --> off
httpd_run_ipa --> off
httpd_run_preupgrade --> off
httpd_run_stickshift --> off
httpd_serve_cobbler_files --> off
httpd_setrlimit --> off
httpd_ssi_exec --> off
httpd_sys_script_anon_write --> off
httpd_tmp_exec --> off
httpd_tty_comm --> off
httpd_unified --> off
httpd_use_cifs --> off
httpd_use_fusefs --> off
httpd_use_gpg --> off
httpd_use_nfs --> off
httpd_use_openstack --> off
httpd_use_sasl --> off
httpd_verify_dns --> off
```

Comment: Thank you! setenforce 0 resolve my issue

Comment: @Kamal Ok, good!

Comment: *Please* don't do this in a secure environment, turning off security policies is a band-aid fix and makes the system insecure.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. I tried @joebarbere solution of running the below command  which fixed the issue but I was concerned about security

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_relay 1
```

I then came across the following solution

https://serverfault.com/questions/634294/nodejs-nginx-error-13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstream

I was using non standard port and SELinux was blocking the port.
Use the following command to check if the port is allowed

```
sudo semanage port --list | grep 4343
```

And added the port to allowed list

```
sudo semanage port --add --type http_port_t --proto tcp 4343
```

I restarted the nginx service, then the url was accessible. I would assume this is more secure.

Comment: thank you! what operating system you're on? I'm using CentOS Stream release 9 and this solved my issue

Comment: I was using CentOS 7

Answer (score 4):

13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx on centos server -

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

Answer (score 2):

I’ve run into this problem too. I'm using Nginx with HHVM, below solution fixed my issue:

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/etc/nginx/fastcgi_temp(/.*)?"

sudo restorecon -R -v /etc/nginx/fastcgi_temp
```

Answer (score 2):

Another reason could be; you are accessing your application through nginx using proxy but you did not add `gunicorn.sock` file for proxy with gunicorn.

You need to add a proxy file path in nginx configuration.

```
location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/myproject/gunicorn.sock;
    }
```

Here is a nice tutorial with step by step implementation of this

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#configure-nginx-to-proxy-pass-to-gunicorn

Note: if you did not created `anyname.sock` file you have to create if first, either use above or any other method or tutorial to create it.

Comment: I do not think you need to use a gunicorn.sock file. That is optional. You should be able to setup Nginx, Gunicorn, and Django without a gunicorn.sock if desired.

Answer (score 0):

The SELinux Policy management tool has a set of standard ports that are allowed.
Usually `8001`, 5000, 4000, etc are not one of them.

##### Step 1

check if the port you are trying to use is allowed (or assigned to something else)

```
sudo semanage port --list | grep http_port_t
```

Output

```
http_port_t  tcp  80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
```

You can also confirm its use (assigned to something else)

```
sudo semanage port --list | grep 8001
```

##### Step 2

If it is not available then you can either add it or use one of the above options

###### Option 1

To add the port.

```
sudo semanage port --add --type http_port_t --proto tcp 8001
```

###### Option 2 (I recommend)

To use one of the allowed ports (instead of adding a new one)

```
server {
    ....

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        ...
    }
}
```

In our case, we have changed 8001 to 9000.

**Note**: you should also change the port on your project to 9000
For this case is `gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:9000`

##### Security Implication

I consider this more secure than the previous answers

Comment: I am running on perfect fine http_port_t 9000, however, i still have the same error

Comment: Hey @Wang, this solution assumes all other setups on your server are good such as Nginx and project-specific settings and the only thing that is denying your requests is *SELinux Policy management* for denying ports. You can also visit [Using NGINX and NGINX Plus with SELinux](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was fixed (from [this blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/)) by running the command: `semanage permissive -a httpd_t` and restarting NGINX service.

Comment: this is an insecure fix in the long run. Better approach is to check logs, and correct the labels that are causing SELinux to behave in that way.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue while deploying my Django application locally with Nginx as a reverse proxy. The error message `(13: Permission denied)` while connecting to upstream typically indicates a permission problem with accessing the upstream server, in this case, your Django app.

The solution that worked for me was related to the **nginx.conf** file. Inside this file, the user directive plays a significant role, as it defines the user and group that Nginx runs as. Sometimes, a comment preceding the user directive can cause permission issues.

To resolve the error, follow these steps:

1. Locate your **nginx.conf** file (usually in `/etc/nginx/`).
2. Find the user directive. It should look like: `user <user>;`.
3. Make sure there are no comments (lines starting with `#`) before the user directive. Comments can sometimes disrupt the configuration parsing.
4. Save the `nginx.conf` file.
5. Restart Nginx with: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`.

After applying these steps, the `(13: Permission denied)` error should no longer occur, and your Django application should function properly when accessed through the Nginx proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. These commands work for me

```
sudo chmod +x /home/(username)/
sudo chmod +x /home/(username)/(your_project_folder)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Details:
You can grep in auditd.log and identify the exact reason.

In my case the problem was that `nis_enabled` option was set to off.

You can check the current config with:

```
semanage boolean --list | grep nis
```

And you can enable it with:

```
setsebool -P nis_enabled 1
```

Then you can try start nginx service.

Answer (score -1):

Do not install `SELinux` on Ubuntun 22.10. I did that, and I could no longer boot. Ubuntun 22.10 gave me the GRUB menu, I don't know how to recover: I ended up reinstalled Ubuntun 22.10.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34443651)