# NGinX cannot connect to Jenkins on CentOS 7

Tags: nginx, jenkins, centos, access-denied, centos7

I have installed Jenkins CI on Cent OS 7 machine as well as NGinX and configured reverse proxy  as outlined in the [document](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy). I can connect to Jenkins via port 8080, but cannot via port 80. I see the following error in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

`2014/09/22 22:12:35 [crit] 1639#0: *4 connect() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.10.81.212, server: 10.10.81.82, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "10.10.81.82"`

Does anyone has any idea what causes the problem?

P.S. I used the similar setup on CentOS 6.4 and everything was fine.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It seemed to be a SELinux related problem. As suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948527/13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx?rq=1) I have tried using

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

and everything works fine after that.

Comment: Thank you so much! SELinux just cost me two hours that I'll never got back and there was so little reason in the log files for nginx to find out why!

Comment: Quality! I wish I would have found this post earlier thanks a lot.

Comment: OMFG!  Another here with hours down the drain, but grateful to at last find this!