# Nginx access Denied with nodeJs upstream

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm using nginx to upstream a server nodeJs APP.

I have this error :

```
2015/05/04 08:41:46 [crit] 5355#0: *7 connect() to 127.0.0.1:2000 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: ws-test.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:2000/", host: "ws-test.com"
```

Yes we have a lot of example to correct but nothing working...

I have change the user in nginx.conf to the conecting user: [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948527/13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx)

```
user adminmf
```

I have change chmod for my project : 775

This is my conf :

```
upstream proxy {
    # Correspond au serveur proxy que vous avez lancé avec npm run startProxy
    server localhost:2000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ws-test.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://proxy;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/proxyWS.error.log;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/proxyWS.access.log;
}
```

If I use the commande

```
curl http://localhost:2000/
curl http://127.0.0.1:2000/
```

My server is working....

But not with :

```
curl http://ws-test.com
```

Yes I have this line in my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 ws-test.com
```

I need help !

Comment: Because http://ws-test.com means http://ws-test.com:80 , where your server isn't listening.

Comment: My server is listening on port 80 : 
    listen 80;

If I use curl http://ws-test.com:80/ the problem is the same

Comment: Nothing else ? Nobady has the correction ? It's already not working ....

Comment: I solved my issue here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948527/13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx

The second answer

Answer (score 3):

If you are running on Fedora linux, disable SElinux should do the trick. (use carefully).

To temporarily disable selinux, do `sudo setenforce 0`

To disable selinux once for all, do `vim /etc/selinux/config` Change `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=disabled` save and reboot

`sestatus`to check the security enhancement status.