# Permission denied connecting to upstream

Tags: asp.net-core, centos7

I am getting the error from nginx server when trying to connect kestrel.sock 
I am using centos7 for asp.net core with mono. Any help would appreciate. This first time I am working on Linux

Comment: Please use the proper tags in future! When your quesiton is related to ASP.NET Core use "asp.net-core" tag ! NOT "asp.net" and "core", both are completely unrelated to your question. Please read the tag descriptions before adding them

Answer (score 2):

Your issue may be due to [SELinux](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-se-linux-changes-upgrading-rhel-6-6/).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948527/13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx).

You can check for errors in the audit log using:

```
sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied
```

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31403848/249431) suggests, the problem was resolved for me by running:

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on -P
```