# Why am I getting 502 Bad Gateway on Django app with Nginx and Gunicorn?

Tags: django, nginx, centos, gunicorn

I have been trying to deploy a demo app with [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7). I am doing this on a CentOS 7 in Virtualbox.

However, I am getting `502 Bad Gateway`. How can I fix this?

**server {} block in nginx.conf file**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 172.16.16.215;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/michel/myproject;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/michel/myproject/myproject.sock;
        }
    }
```

**gunicorn.service file**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=michel
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/michel/myproject
ExecStart=/home/michel/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/michel/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**var/logs/nginx/error.log**

```
2016/08/28 18:55:14 [crit] 17557#0: *4 connect() to unix:/home/michel/myproject/myproject.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.16.23, server: 172.16.16.217, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/michel/myproject/myproject.sock:/", host: "172.16.16.217"
```

Comment: Would you mind look at the nginx error message? Maybe in var/logs/nginx/error.log

Comment: @Aison `2016/08/28 14:11:35 [crit] 2181#0: *15 connect() to unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.16.23, server: 172.16.16.215, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/root/myproject/myproject.sock:/", host: "172.16.16.215"`

Comment: It tells you nginx can't find your sock file. I guess the SOCKET PATH of your gunicorn or supervisors is wrong.

Comment: Where can I change that setting?

Comment: @Aison Is the sock file auto created? Or do I have to create it manually?

Comment: Check the gunicorn log and it should have the errors why sock file creation failed.

Comment: @MiniGunnR, yes it's auto created.

Comment: @Aison I got the sock file to be created, but now it shows permission error. I have updated my question. Also, the sock file (symlink) has 777 permission, so I don't know why it can't be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied | audit2allow -M mynginx
sudo semodule -i mynginx.pp
```

This was copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948527/13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx).

Answer (score 1):

Gunicorn does not have right to save `.sock` file, or nginx does not have right to read `.sock` file.

Move this file to `/tmp/` folder:

**nginx.conf**

```
proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/myproject.sock:/;
```

**gunicorn.service**

```
ExecStart=/home/michel/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/tmp/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
```

Comment: `srwxrwxrwx. 1 michel nginx      0 Aug 28 18:48 myproject.sock` this is the permission for the sock file. I don't think moving it to /tmp folder will do any good if it has 777 permission, will it?

Comment: Look at this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88083/idiomatic-location-for-file-based-sockets-on-debian-systems `/tmp` is the best choice.

Comment: I've disabled SELinux and it works now. However, I will take a look at your link.

Comment: If You don't care about security... ok, but none of administrators would not agree to it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. What solved the issue for me was running:

```
chmod 711 on the home directory
```

This allowed nginx to access the .sock file in the run folder. This permission error did not happen to me on Ubuntu, but was present on Amazon Linux 2, which is derived from Cent OS. These [django deployment scripts](https://github.com/dancaron/djangogo) may help others facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities to get **502 badgateway** , check with below cmds..

1. `sudo systemctl status gunicorn`
2. `sudo systemctl status nginx`
3. `gunicorn --log-file=- projectname.wsgi:application`

   These above result should be in active mode

Answer (score -2):

I disabled SELinux and the application worked.

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

Set `SELINUX=disabled`.

Save and exit. RESTART.

Comment: Better way is understand why You don't have permissions. Read some tutorials.

Comment: SELinux handles the internal security. You shouldn't disable this. Instead, you should use something like `audit2allow` and have that generate a SELinux policy to allow binding to sockets.

Comment: Fixed it without disabling SELinux. Check my other answer.