# How to setup nginx infront of Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx

I am following [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/playing-http-tricks-nginx) tutorial to setup nginx infront of Elasticsearch on CentOS 7. I am trying to run first (very simple) example in this tutorial. Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
        }
    }

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

After restarting nginx, running 
`curl 'localhost:8080/_nodes/stats/http?pretty'` gives:

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.4</center>
</body>
</html>
```

While `localhost:9200` works as expected. In /var/log/nginx/error.log four lines are written:

```
2017/08/17 14:56:48 [crit] 38481#38481: *4 connect() to [::1]:9200 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /_nodes/stats/http?pretty HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:9200/_nodes/stats/http?pretty", host: "localhost:8080"
2017/08/17 14:56:48 [warn] 38481#38481: *4 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /_nodes/stats/http?pretty HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:9200/_nodes/stats/http?pretty", host: "localhost:8080"
2017/08/17 14:56:48 [crit] 38481#38481: *4 connect() to 127.0.0.1:9200 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /_nodes/stats/http?pretty HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes/stats/http?pretty", host: "localhost:8080"
2017/08/17 14:56:48 [warn] 38481#38481: *4 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /_nodes/stats/http?pretty HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes/stats/http?pretty", host: "localhost:8080"
```

Why is there permission denied? Should I set some permissions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948527/13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx

Answer (score -1):

```
2017/08/17 14:56:48 [crit] 38481#38481: *4 connect() to [::1]:9200 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

It seems like the user nginx does not have enough permission to do connect(). you can do a work around: change the line 1 of your nginx.conf to :

```
user root
```

And try it.