# loadbalancing no live upstreams while connecting to upstream client

Tags: nginx

Im setting up a load balancer with two docker apache instances on my local network. Both nodes I confirm are up and can view on individual ports 8081 and 8082 but when trying use upstream in apache I get 502 bad gateway error.

I have tried changing permissions on /etc/nginx directory to nginx user. I have tried restarting apache instances and nginx service. When I change server_name to localhost instead of ip address of the server host then I can see default nginx server page on my web browser from another machine on my local network. If I change it back to IP address I get the bad gateway error.

I have my default.conf symlinked to sites-available

```
    [root@www nginx]# vi sites-enabled/default.conf
    upstream containerapp {
        server 192.168.0.42:8081;
        server 192.168.0.42:8082;
     } 

      server {
        listen *:80;

        server_name localhost;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/localweb.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/localerr.log;

        location /{
                proxy_pass http://containerapp;
        }
     }
```

This is the log file error I get

```
    [root@www nginx]# cat /var/log/nginx/localerr.log
    referrer: "http://192.168.0.42/"
    2019/01/04 20:15:54 [error] 16310#0: *1 no live upstreams while 
    connecting 
    to upstream, client: 192.168.0.18, server: 192.168.0.42, request: 
    "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://containerapp/", 
    host:"192.168.0.42"
    2019/01/04 20:15:54 [error] 16310#0: *1 no live upstreams while 
    connecting 
    to upstream, client: 192.168.0.18, server: 192.168.0.42, request: 
    "GET 
    /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://containerapp/favicon.ico", 
    host: 
    "192.168.0.42", referrer: "http://192.168.0.42/"
```

This is how my nginx.conf looks

```
 nginx.conf
        user nginx;
        worker_processes auto;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        pid /run/nginx.pid;

    # Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
    include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
    }

    http {
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] 
   "$request" '    
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile            on;
        tcp_nopush          on;
        tcp_nodelay         on;
        keepalive_timeout   65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d 
    directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
       listen       80 default_server;
       listen       [::]:80 default_server;
       server_name  _;
       root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        #include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

       location / {
       }

       error_page 404 /404.html;
          location = /40x.html {
       }

       error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
           location = /50x.html {
       }
    }

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
```

I can hit http://192.168.0.42 and it will direct round robin to http://192.168.0.42:8081 or http://192.168.0.42:8082 nodes

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this was selinux related. There was another post here I found with this command

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

link to the original question in case anyone has this problem in future [(13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream:[nginx]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948527/13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is problem with slow response from apache instance.

This will be help:

```
location /{
  proxy_pass http://containerapp;
  proxy_read_timeout 5m;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just tried that and didnt make any difference. This is only a lab server so there is no performance issues and the site returns straight away with no delay when I hit the individual port nodes on http://192.168.0.42:8081 and also I can curl http://172.17.0.2 on the actual docker apache and they both are fast

Comment: Ok, but nginx can't connect to apache. How is configured your firewall?

Comment: I have http and https enabled on the host server and port 80 open on server that has the two apache docker instances