# nginx serve static html and proxy

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a droplet on Digital Ocean, that I am using to host a site and an API for that site.

I would like:

- https://example.com to serve the website
- https://example.com/api to serve the API, running on port 3000.

Here's my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file:

```
http {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/http-error.log;

        sendfile            on;
        tcp_nopush          on;
        tcp_nodelay         on;
        keepalive_timeout   65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        server { 
                server_name example.com; # managed by Certbot 

                listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot 
                listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot 

                # SSL settings

                ssl_certificate /path/to/file.pem; # managed by Certbot 
                ssl_certificate_key /path/to/file.pem; # managed by Certbot 
                include /path/to/file.conf; # managed by Certbot 
                ssl_dhparam /path/to/file.pem; # managed by Certbot 

                proxy_http_version 1.1; 
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; 
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 

                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                proxy_redirect off;

                # Routes

                location /api/ { 
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/; 
                } 

                location / { 
                        root /usr/share/nginx/html; 
                } 

                error_page 404 /404.html; 
                location = /40x.html {}

                error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html; 
                location = /50x.html {}
        } 

        server { 
                if ($host = example.com) { 
                        return 301 https://$host$request_uri; 
                } # managed by Certbot 

                listen       80 ; 
                listen       [::]:80 ; 
                server_name example.com; 
                return 404; # managed by Certbot 
        } 
}
```

Serving the static html files works great, but the https://example.com/api/ returns a `502: Bad Gateway` error. I don't understand what I am doing wrong... any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my config was totally fine. I just need to enable networking on the Droplet. I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31403848/4802228) to do so. Thanks, everyone!

In short:

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  Host       $http_host;
    proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
```

This normally does not disappoint me. Please try.

Comment: These headers are already set under the server directive, and the `proxy_pass` is set under the `location /api/` directive. I want `/` to serve static html that is in the directory above. Thanks.