# Permission denied while connecting to upstream in Nginx with Gunicorn

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, rhel7

Following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial, I tried deploying a Flask app with Nginx and Gunicorn. Starting the app with Gunicorn alone and connecting to it works fine. But, after configuring a Unicorn instance to serve the project and configuring Nginx, connecting to the endpoint gives status 502 in the browser console and a permission error in Nginx error.log. I am aware of the similar question in [(13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream:[nginx]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948527/13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx). But, given my system is RHEL 7 and I don't understand the commands in the answers, I am not sure of which commands to run. The configurations and error messages can be found below. Help me if you can identify the problem.

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen   9000;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /fasttext{
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/vectorbot.sock;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }


}
```

> Flask app

```
import plyvel
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from laserembeddings import Laser
from getters.getIntents import *
from getters.getEntities import *

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

path_to_bpe_codes = 'data/laser_models/93langs.fcodes'
path_to_bpe_vocab = 'data/laser_models/93langs.fvocab'
path_to_encoder = 'data/laser_models/bilstm.93langs.2018-12-26.pt'

laser = Laser(path_to_bpe_codes, path_to_bpe_vocab, path_to_encoder)


@app.route('/fasttext/lang/si/<keylist>', methods=['GET'])
def get_si(keylist):

    return 'Success'


# Initialize and start the web application
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

> wsgi.py

```
from expose import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

> /etc/systemd/system/vectorbot.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve vectorbot
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot
Environment="PATH=/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:vectorbot.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Service starts successfully without errors

> In /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2020/03/11 12:10:28 [crit] 13499#13499: *291 connect() to unix:/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/vectorbot.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: #######, server: localhost, request: "GET /fasttext/lang/si/i%20have%20a%20question HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/vectorbot.sock:/fasttext/lang/si/i%20have%20a%20question", host: "#######"
```

> In browser

Status code 502

[image]

Comment: Have you tried executing the command as root?

Comment: Which command? This one??                                                                     
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

Comment: Your service starts gunicorn and with that the Flask app. It is also binding to the socket. In the service you specified the command (`ExecStart`): `/home/ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:vectorbot.sock -m 007 wsgi:app`. You may need to adjust your `PATH` before being able to run that command (`Environment`). That command is runned as `ec2-user:ec2-user`

Comment: Should the path be `(ExecStart): /home/ec2-user:ec2-user/projects/vectorbot/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:vectorbot.sock -m 007 wsgi:app` ?

Comment: No. Don't do that. I think the easiest would be if you just modify your service file and change both `User` and `Group` to `root`, then restart the service and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Tried this. No luck. Is Nginx routing the request to the correct place?